# Tomcat HTTPS only except 1 endpoint

Tags: java, tomcat

I already configured my Connector in the server.xml with the redirection from 8080 to 8443, and set the security-constraint in web.xml with the appropriate sub-tags. It redirects properly, but I would like to ignore the HTTP access and use only HTTPS. So I do not need redirection or smthing like that. An external service requires HTTP access for an endpoint, I would like to enable only that endpoint over HTTP.

I tried to remove the Connector with 8080 port, but with this approach there is no chance to get the request over http.

Comment: Should it work for all applications that deployed to tomcat or just for a single one?

Comment: @nikita_pavlenko doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable http conection you will not have an access to your application over http.

So you can implement a filter that checks if the protocol of current request is HTTP and endpoint URL is allowed otherwise block the request.

In your web.xml you can declare following filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>blockHttpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.BlockHttpFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Implementation may be following:

```
public class BlockHttpFilter implements Filter {

    private ServletContext context;

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        if(req.isSecure() && checkHttpEnpointPath(req)){
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;
            res.sendError(403);
         }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        //we can close resources here
    }

}
```